# 'Range' of object'_Global' failed VBA

Tags: excel, vba

There are two date ranges which are set. Once this range is set, I click my refresh data macro which will then extract the data from within these two date ranges. (i.e. Date 1 - 1/1/2017. Date 2 - 31/1/2017) However I have noticed as soon as I go beyond the date range 19/1/2017 it will throw an error indicating the range of the object has failed. I cannot seem to understand the significance of this date.

I have checked that my ranges are not unqualified as I have set the Worksheet to "Outage Schedule ->" and I have not changed the sheet name.

Does anyone have any idea why this is the case?

```
Sub SortFinalTable(numRows As Long)

    Dim sht As Worksheet
    Dim rng As Range

    Set sht = Worksheets("Outage Schedule ->")
    Set rng = sht.Range("A5").Resize(numRows + 1, 52)

    sht.AutoFilterMode = False
    rng.AutoFilter
    On Error Resume Next
    sht.AutoFilter.Sort.SortFields.Clear
    On Error GoTo 0
    sht.AutoFilter.Sort.SortFields.Add Key:=Range("A5:A" & numRows - 4), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlDescending, _
        DataOption:=xlSortNormal
    sht.AutoFilter.Sort.SortFields.Add _
        Key:=Range("B5:B" & numRows - 4), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, _
        DataOption:=xlSortNormal
    With sht.AutoFilter.Sort
        .Header = xlYes
        .MatchCase = False
        .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
        .SortMethod = xlPinYin
        .Apply
    End With      

End Sub
```

Comment: What line does it fail on? `Set rng = sht.Range("A5").Resize(numRows + 1, 52)`? If so -- what is the value of `numRows` when it fails?

Comment: maybe `Key:=sht.Range` instead `Key:=Range`. It would fail if `numRows - 4` is less than 1 or more than the row limit

Comment: @JohnColeman: The code fails on the 'sht.AutoFilter.Sort.SortFields.Add Key:=Range("A5:A" & numRows - 4), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlDescending, _
        DataOption:=xlSortNormal' line. The number of rows is equal to 4 as well which doesn't make sense to me as I thought my array automatically resizes...

Comment: I took another look and it seems that NumRows is 4 to begin with and AFTER we have the +1, it remains at 4. The value doesn't change so when it reaches A5, it is still at 4. I don't know why this is however.

Comment: Maybe you need parentheses around `numRows - 4` You seem to be inadvertently trying to subtract 4 from a string.

Comment: @JohnColeman: I have tried adding the parentheses but it still doesn't add the +1. It remains at 4. I added a MsgBox after this and put a +1 to see if it changed in another expression and it did then. However when the argument is passed through to: Sht.AutoFilter it becomes 4 again...

Comment: Then the error is in the calling code, not in this routine. Apart the unqualified ranges of course, which you need to eliminate sooner or later. `Key:=Range("A5:....` here is an unqualified Range.

Comment: @A.S.H: Strange. I'm calling this but it only indicates the problem is in the SortFinalTable module. I have removed the other unqualified ranges so I'm at a bit of a loss as to why the numRows variable is acting up. I will continue looking into this.

Comment: Hi All, I have resolved the issue. I have actually taken out my sorting statement as an interim measure and everything is rosy. Thanks for everyones help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was that the numRows variable was recording a 0 or negative value which meant that when I tried to set the range below:

```
sht.range("A5")>Resize(numRows +1, 52)
....
....
....
sht.AutoFilter.Sort.SortFields.Add Key=Sht.Range("A5:A" & numRows - 4),...
```

The range would always fail as the numbers were negative. I addressed this by ensuring the numRows always stays +ve so the lowest number the range could ever drop to is 1.

This seems to have resolved the issue for now.